# Clarification of code and how it works + how to return to beginning of code?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Just started learning some Python. I'm trying to build a simple algorithm that does a chemical ionic recombination reaction, i. e. KBr + NaCl -> KCl + NaBr.

Basically, I'm asking the user to input the two reactants, like KBr and NaCl, and I want python to rearrange these two where the first part of the first reactant gets matched with the second part of second reactant, like KCl and NaBr. One issue I've come across is dealing with one-letter inputs like Potassium or Iodide, where I'm not sure how I would split the string if it's KBr or KI. I've tried doing this in the code below, but I'm getting weird results like KIBr and Mg.

Finally, I was wondering how I would go about return the user to the start of the code after the last line? Meaning, when the program outputs the data, how do I make it go back in a loop and ask the user again?

For reference 'C' = cation, and 'N' = anion.

```
# Asks user for reactants input.
Alpha = raw_input("Alpha reactant = ")
Beta = raw_input("Beta reactant = ")

# Searches for one-letter elements to prevent mixed output.
if str(['K','H']) in a:
    Alpha_C = a[0]
else:
    Alpha_C = a[:2]

if str(['F','I']) in a:
    Alpha_N = a[-1]
else:
    Alpha_N = a[2:]

if str(['K','H']) in b:
    Beta_C = b[0]
else:
    Beta_C = b[:2]

if str(['F','I']) in b:
    Beta_N = b[-1]
else:
    Beta_N = b[2:]

# Recombines the reacted ions.
Re_Alpha = Alpha_C + Beta_N
Re_Beta = Alpha_N + Beta_C

# Final statement additions, product response, and return to start.
z = "Your products are the following: "; Q = " , "
print z + Re_Alpha + Q + Re_Beta
```

Comment: Where do you define `a` and `b`?

Comment: You make it go back in a loop by [using a loop](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/controlflow.html). I recommend reading up on Python basics before doing any more coding, as loops are one of the fundamental building blocks of almost any program.

Comment: @Dannnno I think you made me realize I'm an idiot for not fixing that. I previously used a and b but then changed to alpha beta whatever and somehow didn't think of changing those variables. Thank you for that significant realization!

Answer (score 0):

You need to put everything into some form of loop, e.g.:

```
while True:
    Alpha = raw_input("Alpha reactant = ")
    Beta = raw_input("Beta reactant = ")
    ...
```

but then you need to break out of the loop, e.g.

```
    if Alpha == 'q' or Beta == 'q':
        break
```

This will keep looping (`while True`) until the user enters `q` for either of the inputs.

Is the reference code you've posted correct because I don't see any reference to Alpha or Beta in it (just `a` and `b`)
What are the expected inputs to `Alpha` and `Beta` and the expected outputs, because I don't think your conditions do what you expect them to do, e.g. `str(['K', 'H'])` is just equal to `"['K', 'H']"` and I doubt this is `in` your users input.

Comment: Yep. I previously used "a" and "b" and changed them to "Alpha" and "Beta" just...because. And forgot to change those variables as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the first issue: consider using regular expressions for parsing the reactants.

```
import re
regex = re.compile('([A-Z][a-z]?)([A-Z][a-z]?)')
alpha_parts = re.match(regex, Alpha)
beta_parts = re.match(regex, Beta)

if alpha_parts and beta_parts:
    Alpha_C, Alpha_N = alpha_parts.groups()[0], alpha_parts.groups()[1]
    Beta_C, Beta_N = beta_parts.groups()[0], beta_parts.groups()[1]
else:
    # handle invalid input
```